# How to use Python to download files from Sharepoint Online

Tags: python, sharepoint-online

Is there any possible solution to use Python to download files from a specific site on  Sharepoint Online using a Azure App Registration? (we don't want to give the access to all sites)

We have tried this using several approaches but it does not seem to be working properly.

Are we forced to use certificate based authentication instead of Client ID and Secret?

Thank you

Comment: See [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [how to ask good questions] (http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Your question as written implies you have made almost no effort to solve it yourself. You should also show at least one of the several approaches you tried as well as links to any documents you have read that address your issue.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis. You are absolutely right. Guess in that frustrating moment I was not thinking on the full process.
Will have it in consideration for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/examples/sharepoint) to access sharepoint files. Please refer to the following code

```
"""
Demonstrates how to download a file from SharePoint site
"""
import os
import tempfile

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_team_site_url, test_client_credentials

ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_client_credentials)
file_url = 'Shared Documents/big_buck_bunny.mp4'
# file_url = "Shared Documents/!2022/Financial Sample.xlsx"
download_path = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), os.path.basename(file_url))
with open(download_path, "wb") as local_file:
    file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_url(file_url).download(local_file).execute_query()
print("[Ok] file has been downloaded into: {0}".format(download_path))
```